# Transfer cursor to JTextField when press JButton

Tags: java

When I click on the "Preview Page" button, the cursor should move to the  Start Position (txtStartPosition). Below is my code that I wrote but somehow it is not working.

```
    btnPreviewPage = new JButton("Preview Single");
    btnPreviewPage.setFocusable(false);
    btnPreviewPage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            txtStartPosition.setCaretPosition(txtStartPosition.getCaretPosition() - 1);
            new UIPreviewPage().execute();
        }
    });
    panel.add(btnPreviewPage, "cell 1 18,alignx right");
```

[image]

Comment: maybe look at the `requestFocus()` method

Comment: The cursor or the focus? If is the focus you can use `txtStartPosition.requestFocus()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `JTextField.requestFocus();`or, the more preferred `JTextField.requestFocusInWindow();`

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocus()
>
> `public void requestFocus()`
>   Requests that this Component gets the input focus. Refer to Component.requestFocus() for a complete description of this method.
>   Note that the use of this method is discouraged because its behavior is platform dependent. Instead we recommend the use of requestFocusInWindow(). If you would like more information on focus, see How to Use the Focus Subsystem, a section in The Java Tutorial.

```
Overrides:
    requestFocus in class Component
    Since:
    1.4
    See Also:

    Component.requestFocusInWindow(), Component.requestFocusInWindow(boolean)
```

---

Using your code it should be

```
    tnPreviewPage = new JButton("Preview Single");
    btnPreviewPage.setFocusable(false);
    btnPreviewPage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

//Add YourJTextField.requestFocusInWindow() here, but not sure if the other information is needed
txtStartPosition.setCaretPosition(txtStartPosition.getCaretPosition() - 1);
            new UIPreviewPage().execute();
        }
    });
    panel.add(btnPreviewPage, "cell 1 18,alignx right");
```

Comment: Hi Sir, @Lasagna
Thanks for your expertise explanation. After I modified my code using JTextField.requestFocusInWindow(); it works perfectly.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help!  Good luck with your project!